# graph of arctan and arccot with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

Please how to draw the graph of the inverse function of tangent and cotangent functions with TikZ:

```
$arctan: \mathbb{R}\to ]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$ and $arccot :\mathbb{R}\to ]0,\pi[$
```

with TikZ.

i want to obtain something like this for arctan

[image]

Comment: arctan is defined by `atan`. Using the property of complementary angles, you can graph arccot also.

Comment: what is "complementary angles" ? @JairoAraujo

Comment: please an example of one of them @JairoAraujo

Comment: Unrelated to this question: I have a solution for the question you've recently deleted (layout of polynomial division in the French style, if I'm not mistaken). If you're interested, you can undelete or re-post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need anything special in order to plot the inverse function of a known function `f(x)`. To see this, recall that the plot of `f(x)` can be seen as a parametric plot of

```
 (x,f(x))
```

Call now `x=f^{-1}(t)`. Then this plot will be

```
 (f^{-1}(t),t) .
```

From this it follows that a plot

```
 (f(t),t)
```

is the same as

```
 (t,f^{-1}(t))
```

where we have, of course, to adjust the domains appropriately. So in order to plot `arctan(x)` (the pgf name of the function is `atan`, see [JairoAraujo' comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537717/graph-of-arctan-and-arccot-with-tikz#comment1358632_537717), or `atan2`, which takes care of the quadrant), we can just plot

```
 (tan(t),t)
```

and for `arccot`

```
 (cot(t),t) .
```

This is is illustrated in this MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad,samples=101]
\draw[blue,thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=-pi/2+0.1:pi/2-0.1] ({tan(\t)},\t);
\draw[red,dashed,thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=-10:10] (\t,{atan(\t)});
\path (8,pi/2) node[above]{$y=\arctan(x)$};
\draw plot[variable=\t,domain=-pi/2+0.1:-0.1] ({cot(\t)},\t);
\draw plot[variable=\t,domain=0.1:pi/2-0.1] ({cot(\t)},\t);
\path (8,0) node[below]{$y=\arccot(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The dashed red curve is just to show that "it works".

Of course, it makes a lot of sense to plot this with `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[trig format plots=rad,
    samples=101,
    unbounded coords=jump,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymax=pi/2+0.5
    ]
\addplot[blue,thick,variable=\t,domain=-pi/2+0.1:pi/2-0.1] ({tan(\t)},\t);
\path (10,pi/2) node[above left]{$y=\arctan(x)$};
\addplot[red,dashed,thick,variable=\t,domain=-10:10] (\t,{atan(\t)});
\addplot[green!60!black,variable=\t,domain=-pi/2+0.1:pi/2-0.1] ({cot(\t)},\t);
\draw[green!60!black,dashed] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
\path (10,0) node[below left]{$y=\arccot(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, per request without box and with a grid.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
    width=0.9\textwidth,
    trig format plots=rad,
    samples=101,
    unbounded coords=jump,
    xmin=-pi,xmax=pi,
    ymin=-pi/2-0.2,ymax=pi/2+0.5,
    xtick={-pi/2,pi/2},xticklabels={$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$},
    ytick={-pi/2,pi/2},yticklabels={$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$},
    grid=major,grid style={densely dashed},
    legend style={at={(0.01,0.99)},anchor=north west}
    ]
\addplot[blue,thick,variable=\t,domain=-pi/2+0.1:pi/2-0.1] ({tan(\t)},\t);
\addlegendentry{$y=\arctan(x)$}
%\addplot[red,dashed,thick,variable=\t,domain=-10:10] (\t,{atan(\t)});
\addplot[green!60!black,variable=\t,domain=-pi/2+0.1:pi/2-0.1] ({cot(\t)},\t);
\draw[green!60!black,dashed] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
\addlegendentry{$y=\arccot(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{``Standard'' branches of the multivalued functions $\arctan$ and $\arccot$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can I draw tan with arctan ?

Comment: @lindaOiladali In principle, yes.

Comment: I added this: \addplot[blue,thick,variable=\t,domain=-pi/2+0.1:pi/2-0.1] (\t,{tan(\t)});

Comment: @lindaOiladali Yes, this plots a tangent function.

Comment: how to draw axes ? and when I put this I obtain the half of the picture

Comment: @lindaOiladali In the `pgfplots` solution just add `axis lines=middle`. In the `tikz` solution one has to draw them by hand, e.g. `\draw[-stealth] (-10,0) -- (10,0) node[below left]{$x$};` and so on. "and when I put this I obtain the half of the picture " I do not understand but it might mean that you embedded it into a different document class, in which case you may add `xscale=0.4` to the options of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: we do the same for y ? and please how to delete the cadre ?

Comment: @lindaOiladali Sorry, so far you have not posted any explicit code, and I always have to guess what you are doing. This isn't very efficient. I do not know what a "cadre" is . The `y` axis can be obtained by adding `\draw[-stealth] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[below left]{$y$};`. If you post a minimal working example those who answer it can provide you with a solution that is tailor-made for your document, otherwise one has to guess, and then getting told that it does not fit in an unknown document setting is not that entertaining. The `pgfplots` solution is more versatile IMHO.

Comment: I put a picture in my question

Comment: @lindaOiladali But this is nothing from with I can infer the settings of your document. Also the picture is not very clear.

Comment: there is axes, tan and arctan without the frame in pgfplot

Comment: @lindaOiladali I added a pgfplots version without box. This is the third question you are asking. The first one has gotten an excellent answer. The second one has gotten three answers, most of which are good and original. In the second question you were also able to add some code. None of the answers you have received so far have been accepted. I think you should at least consider accepting daleif's answer to the first question by clicking on the check mark on its left.